# i have done a python kivy code without .kv file. I have done with screenmanager below,the first screen's widgets are displaying but not second

Tags: python, kivy

I made a python program with importing kivy and I don't want .kv file to be used. But how can I  solve the below bugs that I have done with screenmager? Here,the first screen's widgets are been displayed but the second widget are not visible in my program. In the TextInput, if you type SARANAM AYYAPPA, then the label will be changed after clicking the button SARANAM AYYAPPA. if you type AGILA LOGA SARANAM, the screen will be changed to second, that's also happening. But my fault is, the widgets was not visible in second screen.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition
kivy.require('1.11.1')

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
class AdhiSastha(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(AdhiSastha,self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.Ayya=Label(text='[b]Saranam[/b] [color=0000ff]Ayyappa[/color]',markup=True,font_size='64pt')
       self.Putter=TextInput(background_color='#ffffff',multiline=False,size_hint=(0.5,0.05),pos=(180,60))
       self.Saranam=Button(text="Saranam Ayyappa",on_press=self.submit,background_color='#ff0066',size_hint=(0.3,0.07),pos=(250,10))        
       self.add_widget(self.Ayya)
       self.add_widget(self.Putter)
       self.add_widget(self.Saranam)
    
    def reply(self, *args):
        self.Ayya.text='[b]Swami[/b] [color=0000ff]Saranam![/color]'

    def submit(self,obj):
        name=self.Putter.text
        print(name)
        if(name=="SARANAM AYYAPPA"):
            self.reply()
        elif(name == "AGILA LOGA SARANAM"):
            self.Next()
        
    def Next(self, *args):
        self.manager.current="second"

class DarmaSastha(Screen):        
    def ___init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DarmaSastha,self).__init__(**kwargs)    
        self.add_widget(Label(text="[b]Ayyappa[/b] [color=0000ff]Saranam![/color]",markup=True,font_size='64pt'))
        self.btn=Button(text="Ayyappa Saranam",on_press=self.Submit,background_color='#ffffff')
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
    
    def Submit(self, *args):
        self.manager.current="first"
    
class SaranamAyyappa(App):
    title="AGILA LOGA SARANAM"
    def build(self):
        Ayyappa=ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        Ayyappa.add_widget(AdhiSastha(name="first"))
        Ayyappa.add_widget(DarmaSastha(name="second"))
        return Ayyappa

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SaranamAyyappa().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DarmaSastha`, you have a typo. Just change:

```
def ___init__(self, **kwargs):
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

You had one too many underscores.